# My tableview crash when i scroll

Tags: xcode, class, global-variables

I don't undestand... i succeed in populate my table view but when i scroll it crash without message..

i create my `tabQuestion` with a `NSMutablearray` and then add this in my delegate : `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
NSDictionary    *question = [self.tabQuestion objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

[cell setAccessoryType: UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];

cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [question objectForKey:@"question"]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [question objectForKey:@"reponse"]];

if ([[question objectForKey:@"bOk"] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok.png"];
}
else
{
        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ok.png"];   
}

[question release];



return cell;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't `release` objects that were returned by method `objectAtIndex:` of `NSArray`. It happens very rare.

Try to remove first of all line: `[question release];`

Then check if your `self.tabQuestion` contains needful amount of objects.

Comment: if i only add these lines i have the crash ->     NSLog(@"%@ %i",[tabQuestion description],indexPath.row); NSLog(@"%@",[[self.tabQuestion objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] description]); index (15) beyond bounds (0)

Comment: i find the solution. in fact, the system autorelease my object. i solve it with a retain.